# Permalink to post does not generate page

Tags: wordpress

Pretty new to WP. I'm trying to create permalinks to posts. This is the code that generates the links:

```
        $page_id = get_the_ID();
    switch($page_id){
        case 6:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=9');
            break;
        case 85:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=13');
            break;
        case 78:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=11');
            break;
        case 91:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=15');
            break;
        case 83:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=12');
            break;
        case 69:
            $programming_posts = get_posts('category=10');
            break;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="span6" id="content">

            <div class="row-fluid">

            <?php $i = 1; foreach($programming_posts as $key => $post){

                /*Condition that creates a new row each two posts.*/

                if($i % 2 == 0){ ?>

                    <div class="row-fluid" id="temporary-fix">

                        <?php } ?>

                            <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview">

                                <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
                                <br />

                                <div class="pull-right">

                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><b>Go to post</b></a>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                <?php if($i % 2 == 0){ ?>

                    </div> <!-- Closes the row-fluid div element. -->

                <?php $i++; } if($i > 8) break; } //Foreach loop end.?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Maybe not practice but I'm new to WP as I said in the beginnig. Var dumping get_permalink($post->ID) generates the right url string and from what I've understood WP will use single.php for posts and I've put some arbitrary HTML there togheter with header, "The loop" and the footer, but the link seems to be broken.

Code inside of single.php

```
<?php

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); the_content();?>

<p>This is some arbitrary text</p>

<?php } 

get_footer();

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I can't understand if this is related to your problem but `get_the_ID()` must be used within the loop. Try to get the ID at the top of your script with `global $post; $page_id = $post->ID;`. You could also check for page id with the conditional tag `is_page($some_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `endif;` your query in single.php.

Your `single.php` file should look like this:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So know Wordpress will get content for your single post from `content.php`, where you should define how it's going to look.